# Reading files from server is being mapped always C :\ drive

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io

I wanted to get the list of all files from a folder on my network drive.

Something like,

```
\\10.151.50.50\\OfficeDocs\\
```

In command prompt, I could do like this:

```
pushd \\10.151.50.50\\OfficeDocs\\
```

I have to get the files under the OfficeDoc through my C#  program and this is my code:

```
var system = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\10.151.50.50\\OfficeDocs");
```

But, I got an exception saying *Could not find a part of C:\10.151.50.50\OfficeDocs*

Why the network drive is been mapped to `C:\\` drive and not my network location?How to get all the files under OfficeDocs which is in my network location`\\10.151.50.50` ?

Comment: Try: `@"\\10.151.50.50\OfficeDocs"`

Comment: check this post [Read Files from Network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501278/accessing-a-file-on-a-network-drive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**  you need to give `double slash` when you are accessing the `remote machine`

Try :

```
var system = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("\\\\10.151.50.50\\OfficeDocs");
```

or

```
var system = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\10.151.50.50\OfficeDocs");
```