# Accessing a shared location with credentials

Tags: c#, .net

In  our ASP.NET application, we need to programmatically access (read/Write) a shared location that is not on our domain. I am currently using WNetUseConnection as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials).

But it looks like that I need to call this win32 API every time I have to read or write to this shared location.

Is there something that I'm missing or anything better you can suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's the way you must do it, unless you keep an impersonated thread. But that would be a waste of resources.

Comment: are you suggesting me to call WNetUseConnection API on every read/write call? If so, what is the performance impact you see with this?

Comment: Do not care about performance unless you are sure that `WNetUseConnection` is the largest performance thief.