# C# Cifs/Smb Client Helper class

Tags: c#, smb, cifs, jcifs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing a Shared File (UNC) From a Remote, Non-Trusted Domain With Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)

I need to read/write to a shared path. I was wondering if there was something similar to the JCIFS library for java in C#?

If not, how do I accomplish this by providing a domain, username and password.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you need to read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/684040/559144

Comment: Thanks Davide. That pointed me in the right direction.