# Accessing Samba Share with authentication, No Drive Mapping - C#

Tags: c#, authentication, samba

I'm trying to start a connection to a samba share that requires authentication. I do not want the drive to be mapped. The credentials will always be the same for the share. Once it authenticates I can just use a regular path to work with it. I'm using C#.net

Any ideas ? I googled some stuff and read up on Impersonation, but I dont think it meets my needs.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following Q&A from the stackoverflow link below:

[Accessing a Shared File (UNC) From a Remote, Non-Trusted Domain With Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)