# In C#, how do I authenticate a user on a network machine?

Tags: c#, authentication

In C#, how do I authenticate a user on a network machine? For example, I want to authenticate the user `testuser` with password `testpassword` on the machine `EXAMPLEMACHINE` from a different machine which is network-connected to `EXAMPLEMACHINE`. For example, I am on `MYMACHINE` and I want to authenticate `testuser` with `testpassword` on `EXAMPLEMACHINE`.

I have tried the following but it keeps telling me that, ***The LDAP server is unavailable***:

```
PrincipalContext context =
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, exampleMachineDomain);
return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
```

Comment: have you verified that the connect string to get to the ldap server is working?     Are you using directoryservices or doing this with the windows authentication mode in the app config or web config file?

Comment: Is EXAMPLEMACHINE a domain controller? If it isn't, that may be your problem. I don't know if you can validate credentials on a regular (i.e. non-server) machine just because it's visible on the network. That's what the error message is telling you, I think.

Comment: That is the problem. I don't have a domain controller. I want to validate credentials on a regular machine, just because it is visible on the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **not** using Active Directory, you could use something like this:

```
using System.Security;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
    public struct Credentials
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
    }
    public class Domain_Authentication
    {
        public Credentials Credentials;
        public string Domain;
        public Domain_Authentication(string Username, string Password, string SDomain)
        {
            Credentials.Username = Username;
            Credentials.Password = Password;
            Domain = SDomain;
        }
        public bool IsValid()
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain))
            {
                // validate the credentials
                return pc.ValidateCredentials(Credentials.Username, Credentials.Password);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are using Active Directory, you could use something like this:

```
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

    // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

    // if you're looking for a particular user - you can limit the search by specifying
    // e.g. a SAMAccountName, a first name - whatever criteria you are looking for
    qbeUser.SamAccountName = "johndoe";

    // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

    // find all matches
    foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
    {
        // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand these examples... It says to use ValidateCredentials() when not under AD, and a regular search if it IS under AD - and the AD code doesn't even mention the user's password. What does this really accomplish?

Comment: Perhaps you need to understand `PrincipalContext` before you comment on something you should understand it's context. why write all kinds of code using AD when PrincipalContext gives you more robust functionality / access..

Comment: As I tried to imply... I'm trying to understand. Do you mean that the first example ("not using AD") is when you have a pre-AD windows domain? Or why does it work with ContextType.Domain specified if there is no AD domain? And in the second example ("using AD"), where/how does it actually verify the user? (i.e corresponding to username/password from the first example).

Comment: this works and you do not have to specify a specific domain perhaps you should try the example and change it to fit your use case.. the code is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

If your machines are not in a domain, you need to use [`ContextType.Machine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contexttype.aspx):

```
PrincipalContext context = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, exampleMachineDomain);
return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different options presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/c-sharp-validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory). The snippet you pasted above *should* work, though.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use WNetUseConnection, a Win32 API which allows for the most direct way. In effect, you're trying to call

`net use \\server password /user:myUserName`,

which is what this API is intended to do.

A good example of this has been answered at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials).

Because the `PinvokeWindowsNetworking` function returns null when successful, the simplest authentication code is

```
private static bool AuthenticateUserOnRemote(string server, string userName, string password)
{
    var connected = PinvokeWindowsNetworking.connectToRemote(server, userName, password);
    var disconnected = PinvokeWindowsNetworking.disconnectRemote(server);
    return connected == null;
}
```