# Accessing a Shared File (UNC) From a Remote, Non-Trusted Domain With Smart Card

Tags: c#, windows, file-sharing

I need to programmatically access a shared directory that is not in my domain with a Smart Card.

There is a question almost identical to this one but the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials) uses user name and password. And I need to do it with Smart Card.