# Access to a Sharepoint Remote Folder from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC 3 which must access to a SharePoint Remote Folder.

To do that, during the development, before to run the Visual Studio Development Server, I try to access to the remote folder. Then, I must introduce the credentials of the user who has permission to see the remote resource. After this, using the following code:

```
string path = @"\\tests.sharepoint.es\folder1";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] dis = di.GetDirectories();
```

The access to the folder is successful. However, this fails when I executed my web application from the IIS, getting the next error:

*Access to the path '\tests.sharepoint.es\folder1\' is denied.*

Even if I set for the Application Pool the same user that runs the Visual Studio Development Server, it continues failing.

I have identified that the users who runs the World Wide Web Publish Service (W3SVC) is SYSTEM (an account who obviously doesn't have permission to access to the folder) but I can't change this and I am not sure if this causes the problem.

Also, I have read some posts about using *SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges* but I can't use it because my IIS server doesn't have Sharepoint installed (it is in another machine) and therefore, I can't use Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll as far as I know.

**UPDATE:** When I try to access to the resource using my windows explorer, I have read that OS uses WebDav instead of NetBios. Can IIS use this protocol to access to the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I have found how to resolve the access problem.

I have used the solution described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials/684040#684040).

My code seems like this:

```
PinvokeWindowsNetworking.connectToRemote(@"\\tests.sharepoint.es\folder1", "domain\user", "password");
//manage files and folders of my remote resource
//...
PinvokeWindowsNetworking.disconnectRemote(@"\\tests.sharepoint.es\folder1");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to access remote resource with Windows permissions from Windows web server (or any other server that impersonates remote client) than you must run such code under account directly signed in on the server box. This is caused by "NTLM one hop" policy - user's credentials can be used only on machine user directly signed in to or machine user directly communicates to (and not on third one that this second machine tries to connect to).

Safest approach is to run process under account that have access to remote resource and run code in that process. You can run IIS process under such account, but you may need to revert impersonation back to process if running code during requests.

You can also directly  impersonate particular user but you'll need to have plain text login information. This is most likely against security policy for most companies.

Note: you very well may end up building anonymization proxy - be very careful to understand what it means to access remote resource under account different from actual user's account.

Comment: I have set the account who has permission to access to the sharepoint remote folder as the identity of my app pool (so the w3wp.exe process is running under that credential) but it continues failing and getting the same error message. 
Also, I have tested differents impersonating options but nothing have worked.