# SaveFileDialog and URL as InitialDirectory

Tags: c#, sharepoint, savefiledialog

I am trying to set the InitialDirectory to a sharepoint URL

```
        SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveDialog.InitialDirectory = @"https://sharepoint.mycompany.com/documents/sale/0001/";
        saveDialog.ShowDialog();
```

However I get the following error:
You can't open this location using this program. Please try a different location.

However if I copy the web address into the top of the SaveFileDialog and press return, it opens the directory as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to call the SaveFileDialog on webpages,you'll need custom web parts along with SaveFileDialog to save a file from a given url.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite old, but in my case, I have to solve this issue by using [WNetUseConnectionA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetuseconnectiona?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

This solution will allow you to open the popup asking the user to login to the SharePoint site.

Ref:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/58159e0e-aa45-4d46-a128-596c3d23ff5c/how-to-provide-credentials-to-savefiledialog-in-case-of-network-drive-access?forum=netfxbcl

[Accessing a Shared File (UNC) From a Remote, Non-Trusted Domain With Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)