# How to open a docx file which is in server machine from client machine

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I am using winforms. If we want to open a file from our computer we will call it as

```
  Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + @"\Multiple Documents1\" + lstDocs1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

It works fine in my computer. But if I saved my file in server machine I tried to call the docx file as

```
  SecureString password = new SecureString();
  foreach (char c in "centaur")
  password.AppendChar(c);                
  Process.Start(@"mysys01\D$\Work Area\ATENew\Task Settings Softwaredevelopment.docx","censys01",password,"centaurble.com");
```

It is telling the invalid user name or bad password. My credentials are right. Is it currect way to call the file from server, if I do so will the file open in my computer. My doubt is the file is in server, how will it open in my computer. Tell me a way to open it from my pc. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials

Comment: The path must start with "\\". I don't know whether that's all, though.