# Remote Access in C# returns "Invalid Namespace"

Tags: c#, remote-access

I'm trying to access a remote file in the server, but when I execute this code below to open the connection it return "Invalid Namespace".

Anything that I missed?

```
public static void NetworkAuthentication()
{
    ManagementScope scope =
             new ManagementScope("\\\\192.168.1.12\\Files");
    scope.Options.Username = "ABCDE";
    scope.Options.Password = "12345";
    scope.Connect();
}
```

Comment: Well `\\192.168.1.12\Files` is a UNC path, not a namespace path.

Comment: `Files` is not a WMI namespace. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials/684040#684040) may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.aspx) says you should use **root\cimv2** as namespace. So try

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\192.168.1.12\\root\\cimv2");
```

Comment: You're right. I may missed to explain that I need to access a file inside the server.