# Accessing Files on Network from IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a shared path `\\mynetworkshare\myfolder` which has images stored.

I have a domain user `mydomainuser` which was granted with read access to files in that path

I hosted website on IIS.  I created a Virtual Directory within my IIS Site with an Alias `myphotos` pointing to the Physical path `\\mynetworkshare\myfolder`.  I have also clicked on `Connect as...` button in the `Add Virtual Directory` dialog box and provided my `mydomainuser` credentials.

I clicked on the newly created virtual director `myphotos` and click on Content View in the right pane.  I'm able to view all my photos within IIS.  From this, I assume the setup of virtual directory to my shared drive is correct.

Now, the question is how do I access this Virtual Directory or Files in it from my code?

I have tried below

```
var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/myphotos/" + "myimage.jpg");
```

When I write the filePath to a log file, I see it is trying to map to a physical folder setup within my website folders.

Instead of pointing to

```
\\mynetworkshare\myfolder\myimage.jpg
```

it is pointing to

```
d:\wwwroot\inetpub\mywebsitefolder\myphotos\myimage.jpg
```

I know `Server.MapPath` resolves to a physical path of hosted site but I wonder if it behaves the same with my virtual directory.

Or Do I need to let ASP.Net know somehow that `myphotos` is a virtual directory created on IIS?  Or Am I on the wrong path to get files?  Do I need to write code something different?

Comment: We ended up using the web.config AppSettings to set the unc path to the files folder, then just append the sub folder/file name in code. My instinct says that if the aspx page calling the Server.MapPath was on the UNC path also, then it would read the correct UNC path.

Comment: I can't UNC directly in code as it is restrictive; how do I impersonate with mydomainuser for UNC?

Comment: impersonate, there are a number of stackoverflow answers on that subject. depends on web service, trusts, authentication, etc... Maybe this bit of code could be useful.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials

Comment: @Dr.AaronDishno, I have found the issue with my setup; and I'm able to read files; posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step that was missing is converting Virtual Folder as Application.

```
Right-click the Virtual Folder myphotos, click on Convert to Application
```

The link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173(v=vs.100).aspx) should explain the steps

Without adding Server.MapPath, it works fine.  For example

```
image.src = "~/myphotos/myimage.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the physical path from IIS (7+) using [System.Web.Administration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(v=vs.90).aspx) (available in NuGet)

```
var physicalPath = new Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager()
    .Sites["Default Web Site"]
    .Applications["/MyApplication"]
    .VirtualDirectories["/MyVirtualPath"]
    .PhysicalPath;
```

If the virtual directory is in the root, the Application is `"/"`

What's specified in the `Connect as...` may only apply to direct web requests. To access the files from your application, you will need to configure the Application Pool to use `mydomainuser` as its Identity (found under `Advanced Settings...`), or you will need to grant share permissions to the computer running IIS if the Application pool uses a built-in account.

Comment: This is just not about accessing the physical path but having the ability to read the files in the virtual folder using certain credentials setup already on virtual folder