# File.Copy access to path denied

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to copy files at specific directory from my pc to remote pc (server)
as shown below but I am getting an error message **`access to path denied`**

I tried to copy files to my local pc not the remote one and filed for the same reason

I also tried to run the `exe` as administrator form `Debug` foleder but I got same error message

another question for now the remote pc has no password or username so 
can I use same way but with password authentication ?

```
private void PatchUpdates()
{
    try
    {
        string[] array = Directory.GetFiles(Sfilespath, "*.txt");

        foreach (string name in array)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name));
            MessageBox.Show(@"D:\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name));
            File.Copy(Sfilespath, @"D:\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name), true);
        //File.Copy(SBankfilespath, "\\\\192.168.1.28\\Files");


        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem might be the source of the copy command, not the destination. Try to pass the found file names instead of the path where you are looking for files: `File.Copy(name, @"D:\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name), true);`

Comment: @MarkusGilli Thanks Problem Solved.. Please post your comment as answer and ill mark it as solution... and any suggestion to pass username and password for the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be the source of the copy command, not the destination. Try to pass the found file names instead of the path where you are looking for files: `File.Copy(name, @"D:\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name), true);`

You can probably just run `net use \\\\192.168.1.28\\Files /user:username password` using `Process.Start` before copy the files. Or check [Accessing a Shared File (UNC) From a Remote, Non-Trusted Domain With Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials) for a proper solution.

Comment: thanks I'll also check your suggested way to access remote files/folders and feedback

Answer (score 0):

I got "access denied" while copying from one network folder to the other.
I solved it by defining a specific identity for relevant the application pool, a user which has access to the path.