# UWP MediaElement play from Domain network location (Raspberry Pi 2)

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2, uwp-xaml, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to play a file on the MediaElement from a network location within a domain.

I have tried using impersonation as explained here: [I can't access unc path from C#. Getting access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)

i'm getting Error: 5 'Access is denied' when trying to perform the impersonation.

Also Setting the share to 'Everyone' did not help if I wanted to just copy (or open) the file from network to local

I have tried with the StorageFolder:

```
 StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path.GetDirectoryName("FILELOCATION"));
 StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(Path.GetFileName("FILENAME"));
 var stream = file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read).GetResults();
```

And just with File.Copy("FileLocation","LocalFileLocation")

Nothing seems to work. Is there anybody here that can help?

Thanks is advance

Comment: You can [use FileOpenPicker to access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187272.aspx#set_the_media_source) files on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: This is not really helping me because the music files are loaded in the background. It's an unattended app where people can schedule commercials playing.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e822c960-f15d-4789-9ff2-040212d0a67c/uwpaccess-a-file-on-a-network-drive?forum=wpdevelop)?