# Accessing A shared network drive from a Microsoft Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, remote-access, azure-webjobs, network-drive

I am trying to write a file to a location on a shared network drive on a remote server. When I run my code in my local environment, it works successfully and I can upload files. However, when running the code from an Azure WebJob, I get

> Access to the path is denied

or

> Access is denied

I am accessing the netwrok share using a method as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14870774/3963803)

and implementing as follows:

```
using (NetworkShareAccesser.Access(REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME, DOMAIN, USER_NAME, PASSWORD))
{
    File.WriteAllText(string.Format(@"{0}\TestFileName.csv", networkPath), sb.ToString());
}
```

As I say, if I run this on my local pc, it works and uploads the file. Something is different when running from an Azure WebJob. Is there some extra permission/ security required to access the shared drive from Azure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the remote machine located?

Comment: Well, is the machine with the share available over the internet?

Comment: @PatrickHofman somewhere in Western EU is all I know.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen So I am told. It is the server of a client who have informed me that the share is accessible over the internet. Does this sound like the most likely suspect to you?

Comment: It's an astonishingly brave (stupid) client that leaves an [SMB share open to the internet](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/155177/66596). I'd flag this up to them as something that they ***really*** shouldn't be doing.