# Copy files from a remote windows virtual machine

Tags: python, copy, wmi, remote-access

I want to do a python script that is able to copy log files from a remote windows 10 virtual machine to the script's machine (Windows) as well as deleting files. A developer in my work place uses WMI with C# to do these kind of stuff but I haven't been able to find anything for Python regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSH for that.

Paramiko is an awesome library that can run SSH in python: http://www.paramiko.org/

Comment: SSH is a network protocol. It works everywhere - provided you have the server and client installed.

Comment: Ah, no. The VM doesn't have an SSH server and I will not be able to install one on it. The maximum I will be able to do is to make a shared folder, is there a way to work with that?

Comment: Sadly no. You can try this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials