# Calling WNetAddConnection2 in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am able to connect to a network drive properly using the following C++ code. No user id / password is required to connect to the network drive.

```
NETRESOURCE netrc;
memset(&netrc, 0, sizeof(netrc));
netrc.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
netrc.lpLocalName = NULL;
netrc.lpRemoteName = L"\\\\192.168.68.163\\Storage";
netrc.lpProvider = NULL;

LPWSTR serverPath = netrc.lpRemoteName;

/* Connect to network drive*/
DWORD dwResult = WNetAddConnection2(&netrc, nullptr, nullptr, CONNECT_INTERACTIVE);

if (dwResult == ERROR_SESSION_CREDENTIAL_CONFLICT)
{
    dwResult = WNetCancelConnection2W(netrc.lpRemoteName, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, TRUE);
    if (dwResult == NO_ERROR)
    {
        dwResult = WNetAddConnection2(&netrc, nullptr, nullptr, CONNECT_INTERACTIVE);
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to P/Invoke the same code in a C# program, it does not work. Please find the C# code below

```
  NETRESOURCE netResource = new NETRESOURCE();
  netResource.dwType = ResourceType.Any;
  netResource.lpRemoteName = @"\\192.168.68.163\Storage";
  netResource.lpLocalName = null;
  netResource.lpProvider = null;

  // result -> 67 
  var result = WNetAddConnection2(netResource, null, null,0)
                  
  if (result != 0 ) 
  {
     // result -> 2250
     result = WNetCancelConnection2(networkName, 0, true);
     if (result == 0)
     {
        result = WNetAddConnection2(netResource, "", "", 0); 
     }
            
  }
```

P/Invoke declarations

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NETRESOURCE
{
    public ResourceScope dwScope = 0;
    public ResourceType dwType = 0;
    public ResourceDisplaytype dwDisplayType = 0;
    public ResourceUsage dwUsage = 0;
    public string lpLocalName = null;
    public string lpRemoteName = null;
    public string lpComment = null;
    public string lpProvider = null;
}

public enum ResourceType
{
    Any = 0,
    Disk = 1,
    Print = 2,
    Reserved = 8,
}

[DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NETRESOURCE netResource,
                                                     string password,
                                                     string username,
                                                     int flags);

[DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags, bool force);
```

Please point out where I am going wrong.

Sujay

Comment: P/Invoked structs/classes usually have `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` on top. Also strings might need `MarshalAs` attribute.

Comment: See this: https://gist.github.com/maykonmeier/2eeff09f3cf011e32b73ecf37d558e49

Comment: Or this: https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/499365-calling-wnetaddconnection2-c

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I already have that . Thanks for pointing that I have updated the question.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/684040/14171304). Note using the `WNetUseConnection` function instead if you don't need to map. See also [netapi32  NetUseAdd](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetUseAdd.html) as alternative.