# Copy File to remote windows server using .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have put endpoint that accept the zip file. The endpoint is working fine to get the zip file. Now from that endpoint after I get that file I am trying to copy that file to a different remote Server.
I try below code to connect to remote Server using the below code by referring to micrsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=net-6.0:

```
  bool returnValue = LogonUser(@"ACC\Test.test", "acc.local", "password",
                    9, 0,
                    out safeAccessTokenHandle);

                if (returnValue)
                {
                    WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(safeAccessTokenHandle, () =>
                    {

                         //Destination remote server folder to upload file
                        var pathToUploadFile = @"\\152.158.100.45\D\FileUpload";
                        string fileName;

                        fileName = file.FileName;
                        var path = Path.Combine(pathToUploadFile, fileName);

                        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            //save a zip file to folder
                            file.CopyTo(stream);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

In this code I get error of username and password is incorrect in this line of code:

```
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)
```

I am not even sure if the LogonUser method connects to a remote server. So is there is better way to do this copy file to remote server Please give an idea to implement in .net core 6.0 C#. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: maybe map remote location to a local drive, and copy?

Comment: Seems like giving that kind of access would be pretty dangerous.  Couldn't you just post it to the other server and let its backend decide where to put it?

Comment: @urlreader how to do that and how it solve my issue.

Comment: in general people don't have access to write to or modify folders on machines outside of a domain.  For "remote" servers, generally there'd be an API which exposes methods for uploading files.  Then the back-end would check authorization and then process the file.  (It would have permission to write/modify files with in it's own domain...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve the issue by implementing the Win32 API called  [WNetUseConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetuseconnectiona?redirectedfrom=MSDN) solutions that was mentioned on below questions:
[Accessing a Shared File (UNC) From a Remote, Non-Trusted Domain With Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)

Comment: This is also another solution. I am adding here so that in future it might help somebody. https://thoughtsonprogramming.wordpress.com/2018/09/28/how-to-securely-access-remote-machine-or-server-from-your-asp-net-mvc-website/